# как исправить ошибку RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Когда я пытаюсь использовать bot.wait_for в своём дискорд боте и ввожу команду то в консоль выскакивает
ошибка **RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback**

Буду очень благодарен если вы мне покажите как исправить данную ошибку

код команды:

```
    @bot.command()
    async def guessnumber(ctx):
        guess = 0
        numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
        a = random.choice(numbers)
        while guess < 6:
    
            await ctx.send('Угадай число от 1 до 30!')
    
            message_response = bot.wait_for('message')
    
            b = message_response
    
            if b.content < a:
                await message.channel.send("Моё число больше твоего!")
    
            if b.content > a:
                await message.channel.send("Моё число меньше твоего!")
    
            if b.content == a:
                break
        if b.content == a:
            await message.channel.send('Ты угадал моё число!')
        if b.content != a:
            await message.channel.send("Ха ха, лох, ты не смог отгадать число!!")
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то она типа `async`, то есть она будет писаться так `await bot.wait_for()`

Answer (score 1):

Ты await забыл, вроде так

```
@bot.command()
async def guessnumber(ctx):
    guess = 0
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
              16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
    a = random.choice(numbers)
    while guess < 6:

        await ctx.send('Угадай число от 1 до 30!')

        message_response = await bot.wait_for('message')

        b = message_response

        if b.content < a:
            await message.channel.send("Моё число больше твоего!")

        if b.content > a:
            await message.channel.send("Моё число меньше твоего!")

        if b.content == a:
            break
    if b.content == a:
        await message.channel.send('Ты угадал моё число!')
    if b.content != a:
        await message.channel.send("Ха ха, лох, ты не смог отгадать число!!")
```